# Field Integrity Exception while deploying Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, field-integrity-exception

I've a flow which saves fine and as of now do not run into issues on dev sandbox. However , when I try to deploy this to Test org I run into Field Integrity Exception.

As a series of tests to find out what is going wrong I removed all the assignments on the main flow so now I just have the main flow which calls another subflow (which has some plugin and invocable apex calls), but I still get the same exception. I can't understand what can be the reason behind this?

I did raise a SF case but it's been almost 2 weeks now and still they couldn't give a proper reason or workaround for this.

Has anybody faced something similar ?

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: I had a similar problem when I relied on a field from a Salesforce app that was enabled on the development org but not enabled in the target org.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the "field integrity exception" error and was now able to resolve it, maybe this helps you as well. This was my situation when I looked on the flow in the system:

1. I had a lot of versions in the system, quite close to or even at the limit of 50 versions
2. The latest version of the flow was in Draft state
3. The second latest version of the flow was Active

Same like you I struggled with the error message because it does not point anywhere. **Deleting around 10 of the oldest version and deactivating the second version which was active solved the problem.** I was able to deploy the new version (btw in an Active state) to my sandbox.

Hope this helps anyone reading this. Really strange behavior & error message tbh.

Comment: I vaguely recall that when deploying a flow, it deploys the most recent version, whether it is active or not. This tripped me up a few times as the most recent wasn't the active one.

Comment: @A. Kaspar Thank you for sharing this